# django- get_queryset() value inheritance

Tags: python, django

I am not sure if my wording in the title is appropriate, so please see my description of my doubt below.

In "def get_queryset(self)", I filtered the result and then pass this filtered result to queryset.

Then in the "def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):"I want to use the Filtered result of "get_queryset"  to do a calculation. But the thing is the final result I got doesn't apply the filter.

So I suspect that the "get_queryset" in get_context_data is not getting the value from the "def get_queryset".

Please help correct me, thanks in advance.

**views.py**

```
class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''.join(
        [
            reverse('result'),
            '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),  <--do I need to change "POST" into "USER"？
            '&region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
        ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST': 
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
                return queryset   《--if this queryset result go to the "get_queryset()" of "def get_context_data"--》？
        return Result.objects.all()
```

**test views.py based on Danniel's suggestion**

```
class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''.join(
        [
            reverse('result'),
            '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),  <--do I need to change "POST" into "USER"？
            '&region=',self.request.POST.get('region')
        ]
        )

class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.filter(region='EU')   <--- there exists already "EU" in the database--->
```

**traceback on the test views.py**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
164.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\response.py" in render
158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
135.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
72.             context = make_context(context, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\context.py" in make_context
272.             context.push(original_context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\context.py" in push
55.         return ContextDict(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\template\context.py" in __init__
20.         super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /dupont_list/
Exception Value: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

**result  models.py**

```
class Result(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    region=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    sales=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=3,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the form is valid?

Comment: Hi @Rod Xavier , the form is valid, I could display the result.

Comment: Yeah, have you tried adding `return Result.objects.filter(region='someregion')` to the top of your get_queryset function to see if it works if it bypasses the function logic/

Comment: @Elena no, I mean put it at the top of get_queryset. It's like replacing your whole get_queryset function with a line that ALWAYS returns the filtered queryset. If that function doesn't work, then you know it's some inheritance error. If that function does work, then you know it's an error in your logic. The reason I suggest this is similar to Rod Xavier's - this helps you verify that your logic is evaluating as you expect

Comment: Hi @Devin Howard, sorry for my poor understanding. So the code is like:  def get_queryset(self):
return Result.objects.filter(region='EU'), right? And it reports error. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi@Rod Xavier, if my understanding from Devin is correct, then it reports "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence" on the line of context.py 's super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs).

Comment: @Elena this is too complicated to diagnose over comments. You'll have to update your question with the new code you tried, and the errors you got.

The short answer is: your code should work, so I suspect it's to do with your form validation. We now need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Hi@Devin Howard, please see updated test views.py and error traceback based on your suggestion, your any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Elena Please note that `self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))` returns a dictionary whose key is `sales__sum` and value the sum itself : I'm not sure that's what you want. But I don't think that's causing the error. Can you post your `Result` model ?

Comment: Hi @albar, please see updated Result model. Yes, I want to get the sum of sales which is the filtered result by region and company (the form information).